# How to clear the terminal of the directory details in VSCode for 'C' language?

Tags: c, vscode-extensions

Tried: CodeRunner extension for VSCode

[image: First Run]

[image: Second Run]

I have used CodeRunner extension which works pretty good for Python, but not proper for 'C'. The problem as far as I understand is the improper cleaning of the terminal which multiplies the space for subsequent runs as seen in the pictures below. I was expecting just "Hello World". The problem is not to clear the terminal, I wanted to clean the terminal if unwanted info like the directories.

Comment: Have you simply tried typing `clear` at the prompt? (don't have VScode on this box, but should work) (note: `clear` just outputs whatever lines are needed to scroll the screen until it is clear -- the scrollback buffer still contains the output) Generally I tell folks to not worry about the additional lines on the terminal window, all you really care about is the new output. If you want to use text-windowing, etc.., then use a *Curses* library like `ncurses` which will take care of the screen on init.

Comment: On Windows I think the command is `cls`.

Comment: What do you mean by "_info like the directories_"? Would you mind to mark it in the screenshots? Are you aware that C is a compiled language in contrast to the (mainly) interpreted language Python? You could also [edit] your question to show the expected content of the view.

Comment: My question is not about clearing the terminal. I am aware that C is a compiled language. I just want to get rid of the "cd DirectoryName", etc. I just wanted to know if there's a way for it or is it not possible.